Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on RPI 5 8Gb - LOTS OF ...."Application" is not Responding
Glances monitoring results
Hi,
I did install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS recently.  Did install some Gnome extensions to customize my Desktop.  Started to get LOTS (Storm) of messages saying:  "Application" is not responding.  Force Quit Wait
It happends all the time.  Running Firefox 126.0 (Safe-Mode or not..)  Running Chromium Version 124.0.6367.201 (Official Build) built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 24.04 (64-bit),,,Every single applications are getting this unbearable message every few seconds..
I am not an expert..  So please advise on how to stabilize my RPI 5 .  LOVE this OS.  Had Ubuntu 23.10 during a few months and was satisfy knowing it was not a "stable" release.  Now this "stable" release is getting worse and worse because of this.
Thanks in advance for your Help !
Brgds.
